# veins examples cannot load library

Tags: veins, sumo

I'm a master student beginner in simulations with omnet++. It's my first installation of omnet + veins + sumo for IVC simulations.

I follow the [veins tutorial](http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/)

I have omnet 5.5.1 sumo 1.3.1 veins 5.0
When I want to run veins examples I have this error:

```
 <!> Error: Cannot load library '../../src//libveins.dll': cant find！

End.

Simulation terminated with exit code: 1
Working directory: D:/omnetpp-5.5.1/samples/veins/examples/veins
Command line: ../../../../bin/opp_run.exe -m -n .;../../src/veins --image-path=../../images -l ../../src/veins omnetpp.ini

Environment variables:
OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=D:\omnetpp-5.5.1\images
PATH=;D:/omnetpp-5.5.1/samples/veins/src;D:\omnetpp-5.5.1\bin;D:\omnetpp-5.5.1\tools\win64\mingw64\bin;D:\omnetpp-5.5.1\tools\win64\usr\bin;;D:/omnetpp-5.5.1/ide/jre/bin/server;D:/omnetpp-5.5.1/ide/jre/bin;D:/omnetpp-5.5.1/ide/jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin;D:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\;C:\CTEX\UserData\miktex\bin;C:\CTEX\MiKTeX\miktex\bin;C:\CTEX\CTeX\ctex\bin;C:\CTEX\CTeX\cct\bin;C:\CTEX\CTeX\ty\bin;C:\CTEX\Ghostscript\gs9.05\bin;C:\CTEX\GSview\gsview;C:\CTEX\WinEdt;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\mingw64\bin;D:\Program Files\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin;%SUMO_HOME%\bin;D:\python37\Scripts\;D:\python37\;C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;%OPENCV_HOME;;D:\omnetpp-5.5.1\ide;
```

Thanks a lot for any answer.

Comment: Can you confirm that file it can’t seem to find is, indeed, there? If it is not: was building the simulation successful? If it was: could you try on another machine or in, e.g., the “Instant Veins” virtual machine?

Comment: Thanks a lot.I can find libveins.dll file and the simulation was builded successfully.Then I install the omnet++ again.Ifirst run veins examples successfully,but the second time the same questins occurs.

Comment: Did you change anything in-between the first run (which you say was successful) and the second run? Maybe you moved files somewhere else?

Comment: No,i do the same things as the first run

Comment: Did you try in Instant Veins?